# POST with multipart/form-data using sockets

Tags: sockets

I'm new to java and socket programming don't blame me if am asking a silly question.
I need to upload a file with POST multipart/form-data using sockets(i.e i need to create http request manually) to my tomcat server (which have an servlet to read and save the uploaded data. the servlet is working fine when i'm uploading the file from the html).

The problem is i'm getting the following error...

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:806)
```

what should i do..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

'Socket is closed' means that *you* closed the socket, or its input or output stream, and then continued to use it. It's a bug in your code.

But don't use sockets for this. Use `URL`, `HttpURLConnection`, etc. It's much simpler.